# Add a link to a leaflet's popup?

Tags: leaflet

Attempting to use a leaflet map for the first time ...

Wondering how to add a link to a leaflet's pop-up window?

I've tried doing something like this:

```
 var marker = L.marker([34.063298, -118.280126]) .addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Blah blah Village</b><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Test</a>").openPopup();
```

Clearly, it doesn't work.

How do I add a simple link? Or even an image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is quotes.

```
"<b>Blah blah Village</b><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Test</a>"
```

This is a string

```
"<b>Blah blah Village</b><a href="
```

And then some text, and then the string

```
">Test</a>"
```

To fix the issue, you would use different quotes for inner versus outer.

```
"<b>Blah blah Village</b><a href='http://www.cnn.com'>Test</a>"
```

Using your [debug extensions](http://debugbrowser.com/) would help you track this issue down faster.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the static url by a variable containing the url string, e.g. `"<b>Blah blah Village</b><a href='{{url_variable}}'>Test</a>"`  where `url_variable <- "http://www.cnn.com"`